# Did "TextTrack" object change between v5.x and v6.x in Video-JS?

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to move some javascript from version 5.x to version 6.x of VideoJS (ultimately to v7.x).  Code that works in v5.x breaks when I run it in v6.x.

Specifically, these two lines are referencing a 'track' tag:

```
var captionsTrackElement = document.getElementById("trackID");
    var textTrack = captionsTrackElement.track;
```

The second line fails with the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'track')" at line 524.

For a full context, you can run it at the page here:

https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/

The error occurs when you enter some text and hit the search button, to search the captions for matching text.

Thx...

Answer (score 1):

The initialised player adds the track as a [remote text track](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-text-tracks.html#remote-text-tracks) without a `<track>` element. `player.textTracks()` is the correct way to access the tracks from a Video.js player.

That was also the case in version 5, possibly you were able to access the original `<track>` just before player init.

Comment: Yep, that solves my confusion.  Many thanks, Misterben!